Had there ever been civil aircrafts with more than four engines?
The Boeing 747 have four engines, the 737 two, and the 727 three. Most modern commercial jet airliners today have two engines. I know that some military aircrafts, (like the Boeing B-52 Stratofortress) do/did in fact have many more engines. However, I've never seen or heard of any commercial aircraft with 5 or more engines still being used today. So, there has ever been such an aircraft?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Depending on what you consider a civilian aircraft, the Antonov An-225 "Mriya" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-225_Mriya) also qualifies - it's definitely "civilian", as it was built for the Soviet space programme, was operated by a civilian operator and mostly used for civilian cargo after that, but I'm not sure if you had cargo aircraft in mind when you asked your question. It had six Progress D-18T turbofan engines (the same engines as its smaller sibling An-124, which had four of them).

image source

Thanks a lot for your great answer! It didn't realized that there were 6 engines on the Antonov An-225 "Mriya" before, since it's other features and aspects are also very intriguing. It is exactly what I'm looking for, since it's still flying just a few years ago. Sadly, it was destroyed by Russian forces on February 24, 2022 in the still on-going Russo-Ukrainian conflict. Anyways, your answer is great and is just what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Good stuff plagiarising my answer! :)

@Cloud: sorry, I only skimmed your answer and didn't see the reference to the An-225, honest! I think you should have started your answer with that rather than with the non-functioning fifth engines :)

Of course there was one. It had a total of twelve engines.

Dornier Do-X over Manhattan (picture source)
The largest airplane of its time, the Dornier Do-X was a flying boat with initially twelve Siemens Jupiter air-cooled radial engines which were later exchanged for Curtiss Conqueror water-cooled in-line engines. In the typical Dornier way practised since 1916, they were paired in push-pull twins and placed on top of the wing. Three planes of this type were built and two sold to Italy. The prototype D-1929 undertook a two year world tour to win customers, but except for the two planes for Italy, it was not successful.

In case anyone only counts 6 engines, each mount actually contains 2 engines, as they are aligned in a push-pull configuration with 1 prop facing aft, and the other fore.

Thanks for your answer, it is very informative. The aircraft does indeed have 12 engines and is an civilian aircraft. However, it was built and used nearly a hundred years ago, so it  isn't exactly what I'm looking for, which is aircraft that is still used today. Still, thanks for your great answer, I learned something new because of it.

@EndAntisemiticHate Thanks for your explanation, I originally though it only had 6 engines, but your comment helped me figure out that there was in fact 12 engines. Again, thanks for helping me figure that out!

to be clear, your original question did not contain any wording about "being used today". it's a moving target.

The Spruce Goose had 8 radial piston engines each driving a single propeller, enough to lift it out of the water on its single ground effect flight in 1947.

The Bristol Brabazon Mk1 had 8 piston engines, each driving a propeller. The 4 nacelles contained 2 counter-rotating props each. The aeroplane first flew in 1948, was then to be upgraded to Bristol Proteus turbo-props, and then was cancelled before any airline ordered the plane.

The Saunders-Roe SR.45 Princess had 10 Bristol Proteus turbo-prop engines, each driving a propeller, and was developed as a flying boat to transport passengers in great intercontinental luxury. Four of the nacelles have twin counter-rotating props, the outer nacelles drive a single prop. The design was outdated by the time it flew in 1952.

And yeah, military aeroplanes.
The B-36 Peacemaker had 6 piston powered propeller engines when it first flew in 1946, plus two pods with 2 turbojets each added in , for a total of 10 engines.

The B-52 bomber had 8 turbojet engines, developed in a time before turbofans could comfortably do the same job. The Wiki article shows an upgraded B-52H, with 4 turbofans, using lots and lots of less fuel compared with the 8 turbojets.


Spruce Goose was military as well wasn't it?

@OrganicMarble well...financed by the military during WWII, but intended as a group transport...so functionally it would have been a passenger plane after the war. Was my consideration.

Tupolev ANT-14 had 5 engines, Tupolev ANT-20 had 8 engines, and Tupolev ANT-20bis had 6.  All were civil airliners/cargo aircraft.
The Italian Caproni Ca 60 Transaereo had 8 engines and first flew in 1921 (though it never went into service and crashed on its second flight).  I'm certain there were others in the 1930s.

Can you please provide some links for the aircraft? Because I'm having a hard time googling every one of them.

Never mind. I googled every one of them and found their Wikipedia pages. However, it seems like all of those aircraft were in service nearly 100 years ago, and retired before or during World War II. So this is not exactly what I'm looking for. Still, thanks for your effort and help!

Not really. The 747-100 and 200 had:

For transportation of spare engines, the 747 can accommodate a
non-functioning fifth-pod engine under the aircraft's port wing
between the inner functioning engine and the fuselage.

I don't know if you're including transport aircraft, if so the Antonov An-225 Mriya had six engines.
So unless you count those, no*.
*You asked for "civil aircraft", so I'm excluding military types.
